# Determining which way a wall faces in a 2D grid with minimal boilerplate

Tags: python, panda3d

I have a 2D grid of quadrilateral tiles, some of which are walls, some are floor; each tile has four vertices, which are shared with the tiles around it (so each rendered "wall" is at least two wall-tiles thick). In order to render this scene, I need to know, for each tile:

- is it a wall?
- if so, is it a straight wall, a convex corner (pointing outwards), or a concave (inwards) corner? (so that I can select an appropriate texture to use – for the sake of example, ignore tiles that are totally surrounded by walls)
- which direction is the free space in? (so that I can rotate the texture correctly)

e.g. for tile `@` with walls `W` and floor `.`, this would render a straight wall facing east:

```
WWW
W@.
WWW
```

whereas this would be a convex corner facing north-west:

```
...
.@W
.WW
```

Some more interesting arrangements: this would ideally be treated as a special case (with a valley down the middle of two walls):

```
WW.
W@W
.WW
```

and something like this would ideally be two convex corners at `A` and `B`, as if there were two independent 2x2 squares of walls:

```
WW..
WABW
..WW
```

I'm not worried about handling invalid patterns of walls (e.g. a cross-shape of 5 walls) for now.

It's easy to track whether each tile is a wall or not, but I don't see a clean way to determine the other two conditions from that data. Is there a nice algorithm to do this without enumerating every possible arrangement of neighbouring tiles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a 2D bitmap (Used for terrain) to a 2D polygon mesh for collision?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28718/how-can-i-convert-a-2d-bitmap-used-for-terrain-to-a-2d-polygon-mesh-for-collis)

Comment: That doesn't look like a duplicate to me, Bálint, but this one might be: [Choose tile based on adjacent tiles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/29524/39518). See also [this tutorial on tile bitmasking](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-tile-bitmasking-to-auto-tile-your-level-layouts--cms-25673) that's been recommended on [several related questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=tile+bitmask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you are attempting is the [Marching Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) algorithm.

You define a M x N grid of points. For each point, you define whether it is 'inside' or 'outside' a wall.

With this, you can generate a world, sized M-1 x N-1, built with your tiles.

The marching squares algorithm will tell you which tile to use at each position based on its four corner values.

Writing a marching squares algorithm is pretty trivial, by the way.
Here's my [Python implementation](https://github.com/stolk/ascii_marching_squares).

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying a slightly different approach (using a LUT keyed on the eight neighbouring tiles rather than the four corners of the tile), just because it fits the datastructures I'm using a bit better, and it seems to work OK – it's a bit of a pain to manually define the texture & orientation to use for each combination of neighbouring walls, but at least I only have to do it once. Doing the "proper" approach with four corners seems like it would work better in most cases, but I think it would make some other functionality much harder to implement for me.